# Click Once version not incrementing properly

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2012, clickonce

I have an issue with Click Once version number when publishing. In short, it does not start out at the current version, so I have to "publish" it repeatedly until it gets up to the right number. I am sure it is because the published version number is getting lost in the publish process, but I don't know where to look.

This is the publish process:

1. Dev machine modifies the app, then zips the VS project and send to the person who publishes it.
2. The former version files are deleted, then the new zip is unzipped, the project recompiled and published.  It always starts from V1.0.0.15, and then increments one each time until we get up to the actual version.

So the question is, where is the V1.0.0.15 being stored?  How to I get it to start out on the actual version number?

Greg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found it.  Right click on the project, select properties, then click the publish tab.  There it can be manually updated.